# Getting Contrast Value of Every Pixel in Image

Tags: c++, opencv

I would like to get average contrast value of an image and I found working code in processing .I tried to apply this in qt-creator as in c++, however when I try to run my code I get this error:

> cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}’ in initialization
>            uint8_t* rowPtr = foo.row(i);<

In these parts:

> uint8_t* rowPtr = foo.row(i);>

Here is the code I am trying to run;

```
    bool normalizeRange = true;    // normalize results to range of 0-1
    float contrast = 0;
    float brightness =0;
    Mat foo = imread("1.png");

    int cn = foo.channels();

    Scalar_<uint8_t> bgrPixel;


    for(int i = 0; i < foo.rows; i++)
    {

        uint8_t* rowPtr = foo.row(i);
        for(int j = 0; j < foo.cols; j++)
        {
            bgrPixel.val[0] = rowPtr[j*cn + 0]; // B
            bgrPixel.val[1] = rowPtr[j*cn + 1]; // G
            bgrPixel.val[2] = rowPtr[j*cn + 2]; // R

            // do something with BGR values...
        }
    }
    brightness += (0.2126 * bgrPixel.val[2]) + (0.7152 * bgrPixel.val[1]) + (0.0722 * bgrPixel.val[0]);                 // scales RGB to perceived brightness
    if (normalizeRange) {
      brightness /= 255.0;                                                    // normalize to 0-1
    }


  brightness /= sizeof(bgrPixel);                                                // average result
  qDebug() << "Average brightness:" << brightness;

  // find contrast by comparing average brightness with current value
  for(int i = 0; i < foo.rows; i++)
  {
      uint8_t* rowPtr = foo.row(i);
      for(int j = 0; j < foo.cols; j++)
      {
          bgrPixel.val[0] = rowPtr[j*cn + 0]; // B
          bgrPixel.val[1] = rowPtr[j*cn + 1]; // G
          bgrPixel.val[2] = rowPtr[j*cn + 2]; // R

          // do something with BGR values...
      }
  }
      float pxIntensity = (0.2126 * bgrPixel.val[2]) + (0.7152 * bgrPixel.val[1]) + (0.0722 * bgrPixel.val[2]);
    if (normalizeRange) {
         pxIntensity /= 255.0;                                                // normalizes to range 0-1
    }
    contrast += pow((brightness - pxIntensity), 2);
    contrast /= sizeof(bgrPixel);
     qDebug() << "Average cotrast:" << contrast;
  }
```

Update: I have added the java code which I would like to run in C++

```
boolean normalizeRange = true;    // normalize results to range of 0-1
PImage img;
float brightness = 0;
float contrast = 0;
void setup() {
    img = loadImage(filename);
  size(img.width, img.height);
  image(img, 0,0);
  loadPixels();                   // load pixels into array, iterate!
    // find average brightness across image
  for (color c : pixels) {
    float r = c >> 16 & 0xFF;                                                 // extract RGB values quickly (better than red(), etc)
    float g = c >> 8 & 0xFF;
    float b = c & 0xFF;
    brightness += (0.2126 * r) + (0.7152 * g) + (0.0722 * b);                 // scales RGB to perceived brightness
    if (normalizeRange) {
      brightness /= 255.0;                                                    // normalize to 0-1
    }  }
  brightness /= pixels.length;                                                // average result
  println("Average brightness: " + brightness);
  // find contrast by comparing average brightness with current value
  for (color c : pixels) {
    float r = c >> 16 & 0xFF;
    float g = c >> 8 & 0xFF;
    float b = c & 0xFF;
    float pxIntensity = (0.2126 * r) + (0.7152 * g) + (0.0722 * b);
    if (normalizeRange) {
         pxIntensity /= 255.0;                                                // normalizes to range 0-1  }
    contrast += pow((brightness - pxIntensity), 2);}
  contrast /= pixels.length;
  println("Average contrast:   " + contrast);
}
```

Comment: Could you explain just in simple English what you mean by the *"the contrast value of every pixel"* and *"the average contrast of an image"* please? I would define contrast as just one single number for a whole image which is the brightest pixel minus the darkest.

Comment: @Mark Setchell Actually, i wanted to define my problem as you explain in your answer, sorry for not clarified question. The thing i would like to do is that i want to get one value which is the brightness pixel minus the darkness as you explained in order to compare between different frames.The point why i am doing that i want to find the most focused frame between these images with comparing their contrast values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [cv::Mat::ptr()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a13acd320291229615ef15f96ff1ff738) to obtain a pointer to the specified matrix row buffer.

[cv::Mat::row()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#acce30f9c4475038ee86ea8b24e00850a) constructs a new `cv::Mat` header for submatrix that consists of that single row instead.

Iterating raw `cv::Mat` buffer may be more efficient but less readable way to iterate elements. Read about different ways and their comparison [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/how_to_scan_images/how_to_scan_images.html#howtoscanimagesopencv).

Comment: I updated the post with adding java code I would like to run in c++                  @Oliort

Comment: I don't know if you will face any problems later but replace that `Mat::row()` with `Mat::ptr()` and your error `cannot convert ‘cv::Mat’ to ‘uint8_t* {aka unsigned char*}’ in initialization uint8_t* rowPtr = foo.row(i);` will be solved @qtross

Comment: thanks for the reply, i cant try the code right now due to some problems, but i will keep you informed about how it goes with new answer thanks again